# How to install virtio-win drivers for Windows install on KVM

Tags: kvm

The problem:
I am trying to install Windows Server 2016 on KVM but I can't install it as it needs drivers.

I Heard there are virtio-win drivers but I do not what to do with the driver and How I should install it

Comment: Look here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers

Comment: I look at that and when I go to install windows I get no resigned drivers thing

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you're using virt-manager.

I also assume that this has to do with virtio-HDD drivers, as all the other ones (network, graphics) can be installed afterwards, when Windows is up an running.

So, first of all, you should download the latest VirtIO drivers. I found them [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-windows-virtual-machines-using-virtio-drivers/index.html). I'm using the amd64 floppy drivers.

When you create your VM, make sure that you keep on configuring it before you start the installation.

You will now need to attach the VirtIO drivers as a floppy disk device. To do so,
click on **Add Hardware**. Under **Storage**, mark **Select or create custom storage**. Click **Manage**, and choose the VirtIO floppy image file. Under **Device type** make sure to choose **Floppy device**. Click **Finish**.

Go to your hard drive, and make sure your hard-rive is using virtio as a **Disk bus**.

Start the Windows installation. When you reach this screen (hard drive selection), make sure to click on **Load driver**. That's about it!

[image]

Sources:

- https://access.redhat.com/articles/2470791#installing-drivers-during-the-windows-installation-7
- https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-do-you-install-drivers-during-windows-10-clean-installation.3324605/

PS. Yes the it's totally worth it! The HDD performance is about 4 times as fast on smaller operations. So it is worth the effort!